# Issue of table vertical align middle in Dompdf

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I need help to align table vertically in the middle of another table. I tried
`table td {vertical-align:middle;}` but it is aligning, in the middle, cells contents only while table cells are always on the top.
The following is my code of html to be exported in pdf

```
$html = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' />
<title>Generete reports</title>
</head>
<style>
#myform
{
background-color:#66FFCC; 
height:1010px; 
width:710px;
}
table td
{vertical-align:middle}
.style3 {font-family: 'Arial Narrow'; font-size: 24px; }
</style>

<body>

<table id='myform'><tr><td>

<table width='469' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='style3'>fds</span></td>
    <td>dfgfffdfgdfg</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='style3'>fsfdsfsfs</span></td>
    <td>dfgfdgfdgfd</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='style3'>sdfdsfdsfs</span></td>
    <td>fgfdgdf</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='style3'>sfss</span></td>
    <td>gfdgfdgdfd</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='style3'>sdfgdgdg</span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>

";
```

This is the output
[Exported pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRopG.png)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post you desired output?

Comment: The output is there. "Exported pdf" Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRopG.png

Comment: I want to get pdf with all table cells aligned in the middle as the contents also are aligned in the middle.